# A type-level function that encodes a recursive relationship among items in a list

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, type-level-computation

We have a generic class `Cons` that represents Lisp-like recursively defined linked lists.

```js
class Cons<Head, Rest extends Cons<any, any> | undefined> {
    constructor(public head: Head, public rest: Rest) {}

    static cons: <Item>(item: Item) => Cons<Item, undefined> =
        (item) => new Cons(item, undefined)

    cons: <Item>(item: Item) => Cons<Item, this> =
        (item) => new Cons(item, this)

    split: () => [Head, Rest] =
        () => [this.head, this.rest]
}
```

The list can contain heterogeneous items. Importantly, the type of the items is represented in the specific type of a `Cons` value. For example (with redundant type annotations for clarity):

```js
const c1: Cons<1, Cons<2, Cons<3, undefined>>>
    = Cons.cons(3 as const).cons(2 as const).cons(1 as const)
```

I can encode some predicates on this family of *types* using a *type-level function* (i.e., a generic type that consumes mine and either returns it if the predicate is satisfied, or turns the type into `never` if the predicate is not satisfied).

For example, the recursive type-level function that asserts that all the elements in a list are of the same type:

```js
type AllSameType<C> = C extends Cons<infer Head, infer Rest>
    ? Rest extends Cons<Head, infer _>
        ? Cons<Head, AllSameType<Rest>>
        : Rest extends undefined
            ? C
            : never
    : never
```

We can test that `AllSameType<Cons<1, Cons<1, Cons<1, undefined>>>>` evaluates to its argument and `AllSameType<Cons<3, Cons<2, Cons<1, undefined>>>>` is `never`.

The following code also knows that the type of `head` is always the type variable `Head`.

```js
function reduce<Head, Rest extends Cons<any, any>>(cons: AllSameType<Cons<Head, Rest>>) {
    let heads: Head[] = [];
    let [head, rest] = cons.split()
    heads.push(head)
    while (rest !== undefined) {
        [head, rest] = rest.split()
        heads.push(head)
    }
}
```

However, suppose I have a list of tuples `Tuple<A, B>`, and I want to encode the type of lists that are head-to-tail compatible, like dominoes: `Cons<Tuple<A, B>, Cons<Tuple<B, C>, Cons<Tuple<C, D>, ...>>>`:

```js
type AllCompatible<C> = C extends Cons<infer Head, infer Tail>
    ? Head extends Tuple<infer A, infer B>
        ? Tail extends undefined
            ? Cons<Tuple<A, B>, undefined>
            : Tail extends Cons<Tuple<B, infer _1>, infer _2>
                ? Cons<Tuple<A, B>, AllCompatible<Tail>>
                : never
        : never
    : never
```

**Question:** Is it possible to use `AllCompatible` in a (value-level) function without the type of the successively removed head elements decaying to `Tuple<any, any>`? How would I type the argument to such a function in TypeScript?